# How to change the speed of the gameobject moving on the itween path

Tags: c#, unity, events

I have set an itween path for an object to move.And I have written the code as

```
iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash ("path",iTweenPath.GetPath("train"),"time",300));
```

The above code is working for me.

Now I need to apply the change in speed that mean,when i press "S" the object should move Slow,when I press "F" the object should move Fast,When I press "M" the object should move with a medium speed on the itween path.I have written a code for.Below is the code

```
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash ("path",iTweenPath.GetPath("train"),"time",300));

    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
    {
        iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash ("path",iTweenPath.GetPath("train"),"time",100));

    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
    {
        iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash ("path",iTweenPath.GetPath("train"),"time",50));

    }
}
```

When I runned my above code,and when I press "S" key its moving slowly,next when I press "F" the object is going back to the original position where it was and then it starts moving fast ,same as for the medium "M" also.

I need to change the speed of the object moving on the itween path specified by pressing the keys.Can anybody please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/documentation.php), you can pass a speed argument.

Comment: how to apply the methods through code

Comment: iTween.MoveBy(gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", 2, "speed", 0.1)); based on what key you have pressed you can change value of speed.

Comment: i gave the above code on my keypress but its not working

Comment: I couldn't get it working .

Answer (score -1):

This will set the speed to `8`:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.Add("path", iTweenPath.GetPath("train"));
props.Add("speed", 8f);

iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, props)
```

I like to create a hashtable with all the properties I want to set, then pass it in at a later date. It is of course a matter of preference; I just think it makes things look clearer.